# how can I make sure that the origin of the request to my server is legit?

Tags: php, apache, web, server, cors

I am developing a web application where I have to make sure the provided origin of the request trough http headers is correct?

let's say I am expecting a request from example.com, the only way to check request origin(as domain) is trough provided request headers as far as I know, I know that I can control the access to the server trough "Allow-Access-Control-Headers:"example.com"" header but what is preventing example2.com putting a origin header that says the request is coming from example.com?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you cant, as it can be faked easily. if you application requires top notch security then i suggest you look into AUTH tokens

Comment: That was the first thing that I thought but this would require a manual process(I have to share the token with client manually to actually know that this the client that I want) this is why I started to look another ways but It seems I have no other choice but manual process. Thanks!

Comment: If auth looks too complicated then try sessionless JWT tokens. Its simpler then auth and effective. If your api calls is from some website then you can easily validate three things simultaneously i.e. Ip address of the server calling ur api, request origin, and domain name.  All these details can be inserted in your jwt tokens.   However if you api calls are through some mobile app then it becomes complicated to check..  In my current apps i provide an interface for clients to generate their permanent jwt tokens tokens